# Computing the Bounding Box of a mesh in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have tried to write a Bounding Box Program for meshes in CUDA

```
RT_PROGRAM void bounds (int primIdx, float result[6])
{
  int3 v_idx = index_buffer[primIdx];

  float3 v0 = vertex_buffer[ v_idx.x ];
  float3 v1 = vertex_buffer[ v_idx.y ];
  float3 v2 = vertex_buffer[ v_idx.z ];

  float3 min = fminf( fminf( v0, v1), v2 );  
  float3 max = fmaxf( fmaxf( v0, v1), v2 );

  Aabb* aabb = (Aabb*)result;
  aabb->m_min = min;
  aabb->m_max = max;
}
```

The error does not occur if I use the following lines instead of the last two:

```
aabb->m_min = make_float3(0);
aabb->m_max = make_float3(0);
```

On host, I use this initial code:

```
Program mesh_bounds = g_ctx->createProgramFromPTXFile(ptx_path, "bounds");
Program mesh_intersect = g_ctx->createProgramFromPTXFile(ptx_path, "intersect2");

// create buffers
Buffer idx_buffer = g_ctx->createBuffer(RT_BUFFER_INPUT, RT_FORMAT_INT3, mesh->nfaces); // mesh->nfaces should always be 1 for triangles
Buffer vtx_buffer = g_ctx->createBuffer(RT_BUFFER_INPUT, RT_FORMAT_FLOAT3, mesh->nvertices);
Buffer nor_buffer = g_ctx->createBuffer(RT_BUFFER_INPUT, RT_FORMAT_FLOAT3, mesh->nfaces); // should only has 1 normal

// load materials
Material mat = g_ctx->createMaterial();

// create the Geometry
    Geometry geo = g_ctx->createGeometry();
    geo->setPrimitiveCount(mesh->nfaces); // mesh->nfaces should be 1

// set both programs to geometry
geo->setBoundingBoxProgram(mesh_bounds);
geo->setIntersectionProgram(mesh_intersect);

// set buffers
geo["vertex_buffer"]->setBuffer(vtx_buffer);
geo["normal_buffer"]->setBuffer(nor_buffer);
geo["index_buffer"]->setBuffer(idx_buffer);

// create Geometry Instance
GeometryInstance inst = g_ctx->createGeometryInstance();
inst->setGeometry(geo);
inst->setMaterialCount(1);
inst->setMaterial(0, mat);

    GeometryGroup grp = g_ctx->createGeometryGroup();
grp->setChildCount(1);
grp->setChild(0, inst);
    grp->setAcceleration(g_ctx->createAcceleration("Bvh", "Bvh"));
    g_meshes.push_back(grp);
```

After starting the script, I get the following Error Message:

```
***ERROR***: Unknown error (Details: Function "_rtContextLaunch2D" caught exception:
Encountered a CUDA error: driver(). cuEventSynchronize(m_event) returned (999): 
Unknown, [6619195])
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Feels like you have an index problem. Like you might be indexing out of allocated space.

Comment: Normally you should have as much indexes as faces. And it works without the two last lines in the cuda-program.

Answer (score 2):

The OP has already self-answered this question. However, it would be good to say that `Thrust` has already an example of Bounding Box construction, although limited to 2D, see [Thrust Bounding Box Example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/bounding_box.cu).

Below, I'm providing a 3D extension of that example, which uses `float3` instead of the customized `point2d` struct therein used.

```
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/pair.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>

/***********************/
/* BOUNDING BOX STRUCT */
/***********************/
struct bbox
{
    float3 lower_left, upper_right;

    // --- Empty box constructor
    __host__ __device__ bbox() {}

    // --- Construct a box from a single point
    __host__ __device__ bbox(const float3 &point) : lower_left(point), upper_right(point) {}

    // --- Construct a box from a pair of points
    __host__ __device__ bbox(const float3 &ll, const float3 &ur) : lower_left(ll), upper_right(ur) {}

};

/*********************************/
/* BOUNDING BOX REDUCTION STRUCT */
/*********************************/
// --- Reduce a pair of bounding boxes (a, b) to a bounding box containing a and b
struct bbox_reduction : public thrust::binary_function<bbox, bbox, bbox>
{
    __host__ __device__ bbox operator()(bbox a, bbox b)
    {
        // --- Lower left corner
        float3 ll = make_float3(thrust::min(a.lower_left.x, b.lower_left.x), thrust::min(a.lower_left.y, b.lower_left.y), thrust::min(a.lower_left.z, b.lower_left.z));

        // --- Upper right corner
        float3 ur = make_float3(thrust::max(a.upper_right.x, b.upper_right.x), thrust::max(a.upper_right.y, b.upper_right.y), thrust::max(a.upper_right.z, b.upper_right.z));

        return bbox(ll, ur);
    }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main(void)
{
    const size_t N = 40;
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> u01(0.0f, 1.0f);

    // --- Allocate space for 3D points
    thrust::device_vector<float3> d_points(N);

    // --- Generate random 3D points in the unit cube
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        float x = u01(rng);
        float y = u01(rng);
        float z = u01(rng);
        d_points[i] = make_float3(x, y, z);
    }

    // --- The initial bounding box contains the first point of the point cloud
    bbox init = bbox(d_points[0], d_points[0]);

    // --- Binary reduction operation
    bbox_reduction binary_op;

    // --- Compute the bounding box for the point set
    bbox result = thrust::reduce(d_points.begin(), d_points.end(), init, binary_op);

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        float3 temp = d_points[k];
        printf("%d %f %f %f\n", k, temp.x, temp.y, temp.z);
    }

    // --- Print output
    std::cout << "bounding box " << std::fixed;
    std::cout << "(" << result.lower_left.x << "," << result.lower_left.y << "," << result.lower_left.z << ") ";
    std::cout << "(" << result.upper_right.x << "," << result.upper_right.y << "," << result.upper_right.z << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my ignorance but this line stands out.

```
Aabb* aabb = (Aabb*)result;
```

Are you sure this is fine? You cast a float pointer into an Aabb pointer. Can you point to what Aabb is? Even if this is not your problem consider using new-style casts instead for better compile time checks.

```
Aabb* aabb= static_cast<Aabb*> (result)
```

Comment: That should be right. I found that in every example of bounding boxes for spheres in the cuda-examples and here: https://code.rodsoft.org/svn/rodsoft/branches/rtgpu/using_optix/src/triangle_mesh.cu

Comment: All right. I could not find what Aabb is but that seems not to be the problem.